# Delivering Page Templates With Plugins

Tags: plugins

My company is asking me a lot of requests that are "theme territory" for a plugin that inserts a custom types and taxonomies. My current approach has been using 'wp_ajax_nopriv_' to set a function that responds a JSON object of the posts, and displays theme on the frontend.

However, they also have the need to search using the WordPress native search, and to display taonomies and custom type single requests using templates.

I've been using:

```
function my_taxonomy_template() {

    $term = get_queried_object();


    $templates = array();

    if ( $term ) {
        $taxonomy = $term->taxonomy;
    }


    $plugin_dir = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__);
    if ( $taxonomy == 'my_taxonomy' ) {

        if(file_exists($plugin_dir. '/includes/taxonomy-sponsorship_category.php'))
            return $plugin_dir . '/includes/taxonomy-sponsorship_category.php';
    }

}

add_filter('taxonomy_template', Array($this, 'my_taxonomy_template' ));
```

But seems error prone, specially since now I'm about to use advanced searching using wordpress' default search, etc.

I've seen some plugins instructing the user to add the pages manually and set them to use a shortcode.

What's the recommended way to do this?

Comment: your way (in the idea) is fairly better than the pages/shorcodes one. The code can be improved, sure, but this is the right approach. Also, I don't understand how WordPress search should affects `'taxonomy_template'`.

Comment: Could you comment on how to improve that particular code in order to make it better, perhaps more info or where to get more info about the available filters and actions?

Comment: What is "error prone"? What specific problems are you having?

Comment: I was just hoping to get an overview of best practices for this case. I didn't know my approach was actually the correct one but I'd still like to know if there are some recommended, or more efficient ways.